# Change apk made with app inventor using Eclipse (SDK)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, app-inventor

I made an application using App Inventor and now I want to add Admob advertising to it. I need to change manifest and some "activity". 
How I could open apk in Eclipse to cahnge it? If someone added admob advertising to application made in app inventor?

Please, help

Answer (score 2):

I think that this isn't possible, because an apk doesn't contain source files but compiled bytecode files. So if you would want to edit such a project in eclipse, you would have to obtain the sourcecode of your app, which isn't possible in App Inventor AFAIK. 
If you want to have full control over your source code, you should consider learning to program natively on android. 
If you are really interested in android development, check out the official Android Developer's Guide at 
http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html .

A good tutorial can also be found at 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html .